# Why isnt my c code running in the terminal of VS code

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

When I finish coding in the c language in vs code on MacOS and I want to run and debug it, this is the message that pops up on my terminal. I was wondering is there is anyway i could see the printed code in the terminal too. Or if there anything else I need to install that I am missing. Thank you for your time

Starting build...
/usr/bin/clang -fcolor-diagnostics -fansi-escape-codes -g "/Users/xperttakwa/Desktop/learning c/drawingShapes.c" -o "/Users/xperttakwa/Desktop/learning c/drawingShapes"

Build finished successfully.

- Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.

I tried everything. what is says when i run the code is the file name* would like to access the computer.

Comment: Need more information. It looks like you're saying your code is fine. What is it doing or not doing that is unexpected? And since the build is fine if something isn't working right you will probably have to show your code.